# Using a vlookup or index match inside a sumproduct function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: example]

I have two 2-D arrays that relate to engines.  The first table classifies an Engine as either `a` or as `b`.  The second table has a numerical count value for each of the engines.

I want to calculate the number of engines for each label.  Here, label `a` has a count of 40 and label `b` has a count of 300.

I thought the following formula would work...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
            --(E3=VLOOKUP(A11:A17,A2:B8,2,0)),
            B11:B17
           )
```

...but it does not!

Why can't I use a vlookup inside a sumproduct array formula?  Index-match also doesn't work.

I can't append a new column to the second table with a vlookup forumla that references the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8=E3)*LOOKUP($A$2:$A$8,$A$11:$A$17,$B$11:$B$17))
```

[image]

---

To do it with unsorted data use this array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($A$11:$A$17,IF($B$2:$B$8=E3,$A$2:$A$8),$B$11:$B$17))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: That works here, but `lookup` doesn't have an exact match feature.  It can fail if the lookup array isn't ordered

Comment: @rvictordelta that is correct the lookup needs to be sorted.

Comment: is there no other way if the array is unsorted?